# Error - stack trace is suppressed; run last macros / update for the full output

Tags: scala, sbt

```
sbt:scalatutorial> run
[info] Updating
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last macros / update for the full output
[error] (macros / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.wartremover:wartremover_2.13.11:3.0.6
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\username\.ivy2\localorg.wartremover\wartremover_2.13.11\3.0.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: 
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wartremover/wartremover_2.13.11/3.0.6/wartremover_2.13.11-3.0.6.pom
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 2023. 8. 31. ?ㅽ썑 3:21:19
sbt:scalatutorial> addSbtPlugin("org.wartremover" % "sbt-wartremover" % "3.0.6")
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: addSbtPlugin (similar: plugin, plugins)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: addSbtPlugin (similar: sbtPlugin, discoveredSbtPlugins)
[error] addSbtPlugin("org.wartremover" % "sbt-wartremover" % "3.0.6")
[error]
```

What should I do for this error happens?

Who says that your wartremover version was old, so update it.

Is it right? Or how can solve this problem?

And where to use addSbtPlugins?

Answer (score 1):

Wartremover supports 2.13.11 since 3.1.3 - see [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wartremover/wartremover). As a compiler plugin it cannot target all 2.13.x versions like a normal library but a specific minor releases. Update of Scala almost always implies update of Wartremover.

Sbt plugins are added to `.sbt` files but not in the root of the project but in the `project/` directory, by convention it's `project/plugins.sbt`.